# iOS - Choose Twitter Account To Access

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to access twitter accounts on a device but what i can't figure out is how to ask the user to choose which account they want to access. I'm hard coding it to pick the last twitter account the device holds.

```
    if (granted == YES) {

        //access twitter API
        NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {

            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

        }

    } else {

        //error
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is by presenting a modal view controller with a table view that lists the available accounts. When the user selects an account, the view controller is dismissed.